# SQL Server installation is either corrupt or has been tampered with error getting instance id from name

Tags: sql-server

I installed SQL Server 2012 now. When I try to open the exe file from the installed path,

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn
```

I get the following error:

> SQL Server installation is either corrupt or has been tampered with error getting instance id from name

I tried through command prompt too. I uninstalled again and tried again also and facing the same problem. Please help me on this. :(

Comment: What are you trying to open an `.exe` for?? SQL Server installs *as a service* on your computer and will start up with your OS - no need to "open" any `.exe` at all! (other than the Management Studio)

Comment: how can i check whether server is started or not?

Comment: Start > SQL Server Configuration Manager, look at the services.  If the service is set to automatic but isn't running, check the Event Viewer to see what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SQL Configuration Manager --> SQL Server Services --> SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS):
Binary Path will be: "c:\Program Files..\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQLEXPRESS

So, try in CMD from path: ..\Binn> sqlservr.exe -sSQLEXPRESS. This should start the service.

Comment: Just to clarify, SQLEXPRESS can be variable depending on what the instance name of the SQL Server is. You can find this out in Services (services.msc), the service will be called SQL Server (INSTANCE NAME). If the instance name is DATASERVER for instance, the startup command will then be sqlservr.exe -sDATASERVER